# RESTful WCF in sharepoint

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, rest

Can I get RESTful WCF services working in my sharepoint site?

Answer (score 3):

Key points:

- Add the WCF config to the web.config of your SharePoint site.
- Configure the services to run in ASP.NET compatibility mode. This ensures they run through the ASP.NET pipeline that is necessary for SharePoint.
- Create a path to hold the .svc files in the IIS web site directory. Set it to unmanaged so SharePoint doesn't interfere.
- Deploy the DLL for the service.

There is a lot of detail that won't fit here. Read [Sahil Malik's posts](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-9-Deploying_WCF_EndPoints_as_solutions_in_SharePoint_2007.aspx) for complete examples and more information on how to do all of the above, plus more techniques such as packaging in solutions. There's also [an article by Steve Fox](http://blogs.msdn.com/steve_fox/archive/2009/07/08/wcf-services-and-sharepoint-integrating-sharepoint-web-parts-and-wcf-services-hosted-in-iis.aspx) that's also quite detailed.

If you'd like to go in-depth with WCF including a chapter on integrating it with SharePoint, read [Developing Service-Oriented AJAX Applications on the Microsoft® Platform](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735625913) by Daniel Larson.